# What is metamask waiting for when a transaction is pending?

Tags: metamask, rpc

I'm coding a custom RPC endpoint.

When I make a transaction with metamask, I use the sendRawTransaction, I can pick up the transaction on the RPC and process it but metamask keep waiting on something and I don't know what it is. While the transaction is pending, I can see that Metamask is requesting the block number but nothing else. Right now I POST everything to my RPC.

Am I suppose to open a socket to emit an event when the transaction is completed? I could not find much info on this.

Any info is welcome!